# Binding a value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to bind the non zero value in the text field.

I have written like this :

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtHaulZoneCodeLEM" runat="server" CssClass="cagText" Text='<%# Bind("HaulZoneCodeLEM") %>'></asp:TextBox
```

How to make sure the value is non-Zero in this field?. I don't want Zero in this text field.

I am tried like this :its giving syntax error : "Identifier expected"

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHaulZoneCodeLEM" runat="server" CssClass="cagText" Text='<%# Eval("HaulZoneCodeLEM") != 0 ? Eval("HaulZoneCodeLEM") : "" %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: please show us more code. where you have placed this textbox? in any other databound control? like gridview or datalist?

Comment: It can be easily done in sql query. Please shoq more html code.  code behind of the page that you are using to bind it. and sql query.

Comment: I am using asp form view, like this : http://pastebin.com/s5mk6tmu

Comment: if you are binding it with sqldatasource using storeP. then u can easily do it. Please update your post with code.

Comment: I am using sql queries to update the values, like this : http://pastebin.com/7tEuq1LE

Comment: here you are using the 'SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"' and 'SelectCommand="getField"'  can i see the store procedure? because you have to bind the non zero values.

Comment: This is how I am getting zeros in the fields i.e, in text boxes : what I want to do is erase those zeros in the textfield. My updateField sp is http://pastebin.com/74j6mJ1A

Comment: where is the age field in your sp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

> <%# Eval("HaulZoneCodeLEM").ToString().Equals("0") ? ""
>   :Eval("HaulZoneCodeLEM").ToString() %> hope this will help you